# React native app not running on android studio emulator

Tags: react-native, android-studio

[image]

I was trying to run my `ReactNative` application on the Android Studio emulator - pixel . But , it's not working and gives the  following error instead  .

> ERROR  Error: Exception in HostObject::get for prop
> 'NativeUnimoduleProxy': java.lang.SecurityException: Permission
> Denial: registerScreenCaptureObserver from pid=9773, uid=10182
> requires android.permission.DETECT_SCREEN_CAPTURE, js engine: hermes
> ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can
> happen if:
>
> - Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
> - A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I was trying to run my app on the android studio emulator . It worked perfectly fine when run in **VSCode** and viewed in an external mobile device instead of using the android studio emulator .

Answer (score 2):

For me I was struggling with this for days, and then I just updated the Android API SDK to the latest version through Android Studio, and the problem was solved.

If you see `update available` instead of `installed` just uncheck and re-check again and hit apply
[image]

Comment: can confirm, it worked for me